# How to check via script PostgreSQL database initialize or not?

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I am manually initializing a PostgreSql database in a directory using the following command in script file on Windows and Linux :

```
pg_ctl init -s -w -D ..\mydb
```

I want to check via a script that this command run only if database is not already initialized in that directory. Is this possible?

Comment: @Vivek.S thaks for response  OS is Centos

Comment: If the directory `..\mydb`  already exists and contains a subdirectory `pg_clog` (or `pg_xlog` or `base` or `global`) then it is highly likely that the cluster has already been initialized. `initdb` will reject to run if the data directory has been initialized, so maybe you can check the return code of `initdb`